# T-SQL 2 or more Joins on same table

Tags: t-sql, join

im trying to do two left joins on the same table but it won't work and i have no idea why...

Can someone help me with that?

Thats my code:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Sportwetten_Data] 
AS 
  SELECT TOP 1000 Main.id                                         AS id, 
                  Main.date                                       AS date, 
                  Concat(Main.hometeam, ' - ', Main.awayteam)     AS event, 
                  Concat(Goals.homescored, '/', Goals.homeconceded, ' - ', 
                  Goals.awayscored, '/', 
                  Goals.awayconceded)                             AS goals, 
                  LB.bet                                          AS bet, 
                  Main.entry                                      AS entry, 
                  Main.odd                                        AS odd, 
                  Concat(Result.homegoals, ':', Result.awaygoals) AS result, 
                  LS.type                                         AS status 
  FROM   Main, 
         Goals, 
         Result, 
         Main AS M 
         LEFT JOIN Lookup_Bettype LB 
                ON M.bettype = LB.bettype 
         LEFT JOIN Lookup_Status LS 
                ON M.status = LS.type 
  WHERE  Main.id = Goals.id 
  ORDER  BY Main.id ASC
```

Everything works fine, except for the

```
LEFT JOIN Lookup_Status LS 
                    ON M.status = LS.type
```

And of course

```
LS.type                                         AS status
```

Comment: What is the error? Is there more than 1 [status] column in Main, Goals, Result, Main? Why twice?

Comment: No idea, i use Visual Studio and i can click on "update" but then it says "Error during Batchexecution"

Comment: from which of the 4 joins you are doing for `M`, does the `status` column exist? Why have the 2nd `Main` join?

Comment: So to be clear, i never done anything with SQL i just googled all of that and tried to understand it...
But the M? Again no idea
The Status column exists
and i thought i need the second Main

Comment: OK, so I'd recommend not doing your joins like that. Explicitly state what you are joining on for each table, and that may make your error more clear. For example `INNER JOIN Goals g ON m.***** = g.****` and `INNER JOIN Result r ON m.***** = r.*****`

Comment: So okay i just start at the beginning...
i have 5 tables (Main, Goals, Result, Lookup_Status and Lookup_Bettype)
Now i want to create a View with all the information,
in the Main-Table are two columns, bettype and status, with just numbers in it.
In the two Lookup-Tables are the "translations" 1 = Over 1.5; 2 = Under 1.5 and so on.
But of course i dont want to have the numbers in the view, i want the translations and thats why i have the two Joins

Sorry btw for the english and bad explaining...

Comment: Your view is currently doing a cross join between goals, main and an inner join of result and main. never use implicit joins - always use explicit joins.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problema couple of month ago with a query with joins like yours:

> FROM   Main, 
>            Goals, 
>            Result, 
>            Main AS M

Try to explicit the join between those tables. worked for me